# Handling Java annotations in JSweet

Tags: jsweet

I'm attempting to transpile Java model classes to JavaScript using JSweet. The model classes contain JPA annotations like `@Column`. The transpilation fails as soon as it encounters `import javax.persistence.Column`.
The JPA annotations are irrelevant in JavaScript and should not be transpiled. Can this be done without changing the Java code?

More generally, is there a way to have JSweet ignore import statements, e.g., when all references to the imported packages are in `@Erased` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, JSweet just erases unknown annotations, so your code should transpile fine.

First thing to check: do you have a JPA jar in your classpath or in your Maven dependencies? JSweet uses javac, which requires all types to be in the classpath. I guess that the `@Column` annotation should be in there: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0.2

As for the second part of your question, JSweet v2 provides an API to tune the generation of the code. See the [specs](https://github.com/cincheo/jsweet/blob/master/doc/jsweet-language-specifications.md#extending-the-transpiler). In the [PrinterAdapter](http://public.jsweet.org/apidocs/org/jsweet/jsweet-transpiler-2.0.0/org/jsweet/transpiler/extension/PrinterAdapter.html) API, you can override the `needsImport` method to return `null` when the import is not needed. However I believe that you don't need this for your case since annotations are erased automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I forgot to mention javax.persistence in the pom, since we're not using Maven for the regular build process. Is the Eclipse plugin the only alternative if I don't want to use Maven?

Comment: You can also use Ant with the command line launcher. I think that there is a build.xml in the jsweet-examples projet: https://github.com/cincheo/jsweet-examples (but you can handle your dependencies manually rather than with Maven).